# hold messages in a channel until limit is reached

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Is there a way to setup a spring integration channel in such a way that lets say it only sends the messages to output channel once it has accumulated 50 incoming messages. To look at it from polling perspective, I want the polling process to be based on the number of messages instead of a fixed time interval .. somehow poll the previous channel possibly multiple times but only accept messages once it has enough to process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `<aggregator/>` with a `release-strategy-expression="size == 50"` and a `correlation-strategy-expression="'foo'"` (and `expire-groups-on-completion="true`). The expire-groups setting allows the next group ('foo') to form.

Follow the aggregator with a simple `<splitter />` (no expressions, just in/out channels).

The aggregator will accumulate messages until 50 arrive and then release them as a collection, and the splitter will split the collection back to single messages.

If you want to release based on size or elapsed time (release a short group if x seconds elapse) then configure a `MessageGroupStoreReaper`.

Comment: by specifying `correlation-strategy-expression="'foo'"` would it add a hearder value on each of message as foo or is that what it expects in the header to already be there for the files to be aggregated. Basically what I am wondering is if I have add this header value on incoming messages for the aggregator to work. Thanks

Comment: No; this is simply saying use a constant (`'foo'`) for correlation; all messages will be in the same group, regardless of any headers. The default correlation expression is `headers['correlationId']`.